# Disable zoom in WebView or react-native-wkwebview in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, wkwebview

Is there a way to disable zoom in WKWebView for iOS and WebView for android? I'm using react-native-wkwebview-reborn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the head of the document rendered in the webview stick in this meta:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

Example:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

You can inject this into your webview.

```
const SCRIPT = `
const meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');
meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
document.head.appendChild(meta);
`;

<WebView injectedJavaScript={SCRIPT} />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the source page.

Comment: @Peyotle you can inject it with the `injectedJavaScript` prop. In there inject javascript that adds this meta. I added how to above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to change few things to make it work but it was helpful. I changed the first attribute name to 'content' and added Meta to the head. Here is the updated script: 
const SCRIPT = `
const meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');
meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
`

Comment: Yes that was an obvious typo, as that typo is not in the html block I provided. I fixed it up. What else did you have to change? You also have to append it to head with `document.head.appendChild(meta)`, obviously. I edited these changes in. Were you not familiar with `createElement` before I showed it here? When the page loads to a different one in the webview, is your `injectedJavascript` re-executing?